# Como agregar y eliminar elementos de un form

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo la siguiente funcion, que me permite crear un input en un form,

```
function createQtionCheck() {
var check =document.createElement("p");
check.id = "qCheckbox";
check.innerHTML ='Cual es su primera pregunta? <br><label><input type="checkbox" name="option"> Respuesta.</label><br><label><input type="checkbox" name="option"> Respuesta.</label><br><button onclick="agregarCheck()"> agregar</button>';
document.getElementById("formulario").appendChild(check);
event.preventDefault();}
```

Tengo esta funcion que agrega un check al input creado

```
function agregarCheck() {
event.preventDefault();
var checkbox =document.createElement("label");
checkbox.innerHTML ='<input type="checkbox" name="option"> Lorem, ipsum.</label><br>';
document.getElementById("qCheckbox").appendChild(checkbox);}
```

Como hago para asignar un boton de agregar checkbox y que solo me afecte a un  input y no a todos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas @OscarRoa te recomiendo hagas el [tour] para que conozcas un poco más del sitio, aparte ganarías tu primer medalla, también lee [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, primero que nada como detonas la función `createQtionCheck()` ?

Comment: Hola, de la siguiente manera  <button onclick="createQtionCheck()"> Crear pregunta unica opcion  </button>